# modal effect doesn't work for dynamic new buttons

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I have a problem when I try to open a modal effect window for buttons created dynamically with ajax (these buttons have class md-trigger). The modal works correctly only for statics buttons.
If I insert these lines:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.md-trigger', function () {
        $('.md-trigger').modalEffects();
    });
```

The modal works fine after the second click on the new button created after ajax call.

With this code (without click):

```
$(document.body).on('load', '.md-trigger', function () {
        $('.md-trigger').modalEffects();
    });
```

the modal doesn't work..

What is the proper method to work the modal with every new md - trigger buttons created dynamically without refresh page? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the modal trigger in a function like this and then call it on ajax success

```
function triggerModal()
{
   $(document.body).on('click', '.md-trigger', function () {
        $('.md-trigger').modalEffects();
    });
}

//call it before ajax to make sure modal works for the static elements
triggerModal();

$.ajax({
   ..
   ..
   success: function(){
    //do whatever you need to do like loading new buttons
    //and after this call the function for the modal trigger again

    triggerModal();

   }
});
```

You must initiallize the triggerModal function each time a new set of buttons has been loaded through ajax.

I hope this will do the job, I tested it and worked.

Comment: I have tried it before question.. but in the wrong line.. thanks man